# Dynamic List of Messages

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, wcf-data-services

```
select MessageText from Messages order by MessageTime
```

I'm trying to make LINQ to SQL query from this SQL query.

What i wan´t to do is to return a LIST of all the messages in my Messages table in my db ordered on MessageTime(datetime).
But how do I do this to a Linq query?

Table is called Messages
Rows MessageText(string) and MessageTime(datetime).

```
public IList<MessageByUser> GetAllMessages()
{
    var messlist = (m => m.MessageTime)
        .Select(m => OrderByDescending(y => y.MessageTime)
        .FirstOrDefault())
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.MessageTime);
}
```

I'm lost.... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var me = (from m in chat.Messages
                  orderby m.MessageTime descending
                  select new MessageByUser() { MessageText = m.MessageText }).ToList();
        return me;
```

This one worked finally for me.

Thank you all for your examples! I got me thinking and trying different methods. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.MessageTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following linq expression:

```
var q = from message in messages orderby message.MessageTime descending select message.MessageText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure .FirstOrDefault() should be removed, because this returns only max 1 element and ordering a single element list is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.MessageTime).Select(x => x.MessageText).ToList();
```